# Seeking Fortunes

Tags: cipher

Great uncle Joe passed away apparently without a will. However, one of his distant relatives got a note from him. He said that all of his relatives have to get a chance to decode it. Here is the note. Do you think that you can find the will?

```
 Lion(       )Oaks

 Bead(       )Cake
       of the
 Blob(       )Oakum

 Coal(       )Seed

 Wait(       )Lily

 Army(       )Index

 Meek(       )Sash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we...

> take every other letter in each word, beginning with the first letter and crossing “of the” before beginning the following line...

we obtain...

> LO OK
>  BA CK
>  BO OK(m)
>  CA SE
>  WI LL
>  AM ID
>  ME SS

or simply:

> Look back bookcase. Will amid mess.

which tells us...

> the will is amid some clutter behind, or at the rear of, a bookcase.

Comment: Put what it actually says

Comment: the actual phrase

Comment: Apologies for the rapid fire edits